# Google map api v3 - show default bubbles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the gmaps api to draw a custom map, though at this point, it's bare-bones and I need to enable some of the default behavior that comes with embedded maps, namely bubbles for public transport that show up on click. How would I do that?

Comment: [**This feature has been requested**](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=145) , but isn't available yet.

Comment: ok, thanks for the heads up, doc